# node_modules is not created in react application after yarn install or npm i

Tags: ubuntu, npm, node-modules

I have a react project which is working fine on Windows. I just cloned it on a Ubuntu 22.04 and tried to run `yarn` to install packages from the package.json file, but after trying to install all packages, I get some warnings like this packages is deprecated, but at the end everything looks fine with no serious error, but there is no node_modules in the directory. And of course the project does not run with the error

```
yarn start
Internal Error: my-proj@workspace:.: This package doesn't seem to be present in your lockfile; run "yarn install" to update the lockfile
    at V0.getCandidates (/home/hamed/.cache/node/corepack/yarn/3.6.0/yarn.js:435:5145)
    at kf.getCandidates (/home/hamed/.cache/node/corepack/yarn/3.6.0/yarn.js:391:1264)
    at /home/hamed/.cache/node/corepack/yarn/3.6.0/yarn.js:439:8033
    at df (/home/hamed/.cache/node/corepack/yarn/3.6.0/yarn.js:390:11070)
    at ge (/home/hamed/.cache/node/corepack/yarn/3.6.0/yarn.js:439:8013)
```

npm config list:

```
; cli configs
metrics-registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
scope = ""
user-agent = "npm/6.14.18 node/v14.21.3 linux x64"

; node bin location = /usr/bin/node
; cwd = /home/hamed/programming/projects/my-proj
; HOME = /home/hamed
; "npm config ls -l" to show all defaults.
```

node version: 14.21.3
npm version: 6.14.18
yarn version: 3.6.0

There is a yarn.lock file available in the root of the project.

Answer (score 0):

Yarn changed a lot in latest `3.x` version and now they use `.yarn` folder instead of `node_modules` after you start your application they generate `node_modules` folder based on the modules you use.

If you use typescript, you must configure your editor as the doc says here: https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/editor-sdks

If you are using `Vscode`, run this command in your project root folder `yarn dlx @yarnpkg/sdks vscode`